# PHP: Using DB-connection inside of class

Tags: php, mysqli, php-7

i'm updating from PHP5.6 to PHP7.0 and this doesn't work anymore:

```
$con=mysqli_connect(DATABASE_SERVER,DATABASE_USER,DATABASE_PASSWORD) or die(DATABASE_ERROR);
mysqli_select_db($con, DATABASE_NAME) or die(DATABASE_ERROR);

class DoSomeStuff()

{

    function GetSomeDate()
    {
    $result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM my_table");
    }

}
```

Looks like the $con variable is not available inside the class.

Do i have to to something like this?

```
global $con=mysqli_connect()
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can pass the connection to the constructor of a class it `function __construct()`

Comment: create a  class __construct() function, and put $con inside it.

Comment: But i need the DB-Connect outside of the class :(

Comment: First problem is that your class is not valid. It has no methods! I don't think this code would run on PHP5 either.

Answer (score 2):

The main pattern used is something like, pass database connection into constructor (dependency injection) and then store it in an instance variable (`$this->con` in this case).  Then later database calls just use `$this->con` for the database connection...

```
$con=mysqli_connect(DATABASE_SERVER,DATABASE_USER,DATABASE_PASSWORD) or die(DATABASE_ERROR);
mysqli_select_db($con, DATABASE_NAME) or die(DATABASE_ERROR);

class DoSomeStuff
{
    private $con;

    // Create instance with connection
    public function __construct( $con )  {
        // Store connection in instance for later use
        $this->con = $con;
    }
    public function doSomething() {
        // Run query using stored database connection
        $result=mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT * FROM my_table");
    }

}

// Create instance, passing in connection
$some = new DoSomeStuff ($con);
$some->doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

heres something I've worked with recently

```
class Database {

private $_conn = null;

public function getConnection($password) {
    if (!is_null($this->_conn)) {
        return $this->_conn;
    }
    $this->_conn = false;
    try {
        $this->_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename", 'root', 
$password);
            $this->_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $this->_conn;
    }
}

function conOpen() {
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";

$db = new Database();
$conn = $db->getConnection($password);
return $conn;
}
```

Then use it like this

```
$con = conOpen();
```

You can check out PDO connection [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)